# Uninstall Workflow Manager Help!

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, configuration, workflow-manager

Some time ago I thought it was a wise idea to install Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2013.  Unfortunately, it's become more of a headache than a help.  Long story short, at one point I stood up a Workflow Manager server which is now "removed".  I followed this article:

https://sharepointinaction.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/uninstallingremoving-sharepoint-2013-workflow-manager-farm/

Only thing though, I didn't even have the workflow manager installed on ANY related server.  I went through and did the rest of the removal process. The problem now is I'm still getting errors when I try and launch "Workflows" from a list item.  This time it says "File not found".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSGzk.jpg

And looking in ULS I see this:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Workflow.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Workflow.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral

I've run SharePoint Products and Config Wizard and restarted IIS.  How do I make it point back to the OOB version of Workflows?

Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: are you trying to create a new workflow or trying to run old workflows? is it 2013 workflow or 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is two step process

1. Run the WF wizard and leave the farm, uninstall WFM from servers and other related componenets. Also delete the related databases.
2. Now remove / Uninstall WFM Client from all SharePoint servers, remove the Workflow Services Application from Central admin ( CA -> Application Management -> Manage Services Application -> on this page click on WF service application and click delete from ribbon).

Comment: Thanks Waqas, that was it!  Removed the Workflow Service Application Proxy and worked right off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen you have already solved, hoever, for completeness, if you want to do a full clean-up, follow these steps:

1)Leave WFM/SB Farm
2) Uninstall updates and application in the following order and one at a time:

- Service Bus CU1
- Workflow Manager CU1
- Service Bus 1.0
- Workflow Manager 1.0
- Workflow Manager Client 1.0
- Microsoft Windows Fabric

3. Log into SQL server and delete Service Bus and Workflow Manager databases.

- SBManagementDB
- SBGatewayDB
- SBMessageContainer01
- WFManagementDB
- WFInstanceManagementDB
- WFResourceManagementDB

4. Delete the folder “Workflow Manager” under C:\Program Files\Workflow Manager (this is required only if you want to reinstall Workflow Manger later on)

Hope this help some others